# UISlider add label

Tags: ios, xcode, label, uislider

I can be able to add a label to a slider but the label only appears when you move the slider I need the lebel is always in the correct position and the value of the slider

```
 - (IBAction)SinP:(id)sender {


    float increment = 1.0;
    if ([SinP isEqual:self.SinP]){
    float newValue1 = SinP.value /increment;
    SinP.value = floor(newValue1) * increment;
    }

   UIImageView *handleView1 = [SinP.subviews lastObject];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[handleView1 viewWithTag:1010];
   if (label==nil) {
      label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:handleView1.bounds];
    label.tag = 1010;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [handleView1 addSubview:label];

   }
   label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.SinP.value];
   _L01.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.0f", self.SinP.value];
   self.T01.text = [@((int)SinP.value) stringValue];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, when the app runs the first time after installation you save that date in NSUserdefaults. By using that date you can get the number of days between current date and saved date (first time date), then return number of days in number of rows in section tableview datasource method.
 //write code like in appdlegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"installation_date"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"installation_date"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
return YES;
}

-(int)getNumberOfDays{
     NSString *start = @"2010-09-01";
     NSString *end = @"2010-12-01";

    NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [f setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
   NSDate *startDate = [f dateFromString:start];
   NSDate *endDate = [f dateFromString:end];

   NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
   NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                fromDate:startDate
                                                  toDate:endDate
                                                  options:NSCalendarWrapComponents];
 return [components day];
}
```

Comment: Yes date create no is problem the problem is create a cell every day from data create whiy label for exampel date install  01/05/2016 and every cell to 31/05/2016  how generate 31 cell whit label date

Comment: when app is open first you prepare one array with dates (day first to day last), using that array in cellfor row at index path you can give text for label

Comment: give array count as numberof rows of tableview